# How to map an instance match in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, mvvm

I have `List<Any>` which have different data class inside of it, and I have this scenario that one of that data class some parameter will transform.

example:

```
private fun List<Documents>.documentList() = listOf<Any>(
 DataClassItemDto1(
  uniqueParameters = "blabla"
 ),
 DataClassItemDto2(
  uniqueParameters = "blabla"
 ),
 DataClassItemDto3(
  uniqueParameters = "blabla"
 ),
)
```

then:

```
 documentsResponse
  .findAll { it.typeOfDocuments == "DONE" }
  .documenList()
  // which I know the return here will be the filtered I just want to update some value from the data class instance
  .filterIsIntance<DataClassItemDto2>() 
  .map { it.copy(uniqueParameters = newValue) }
```

maybe do we have here a `mapIsIntance` also??

Comment: It is unclear what your question is. Can you state clearly what is wrong with your current code, and what you want to do exactly?

Comment: @Sweeper what do you mean is uncleared? the problem is that `filterIsIntance` is only returning a list of the filter instance of `T` which is my scenario is that I will just update those value from the Intance of `T` within a list.

Answer (score 2):

There's no special way to do it.  Just do it the same way you would for a non-collection.

```
.map { if (it is DataClassItemDto2) it.copy(uniqueParameters = newValue) else it }
```

Comment: actually I implemented this when I know `filterIsIntance` returning only filtered items that is instance of `T`, I posted wishing maybe there are others ways which is simplier like `filterIsIntance`

Comment: @UserUnknown: I know you posted wishing there were other ways.  What I said was that there weren't any other ways.